# Syntax error: Unexpected token ) when building Docusaurus on Node 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, docusaurus

I am encountering an error when running `docusaurus build` on docusaurus@1.5.1 and Node 6:

```
$ docusaurus-build
/home/website/node_modules/docusaurus/lib/build-files.js:31
  );
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

Basically there is code like this currently in Docusaurus:

```
console.log(
    chalk.red('hello world'),
);
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Related: [node.green - trailing commas in function syntax](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-trailing-commas-in-function-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error occurs because trailing commas in function calls are not supported in older versions of Node. Ensure that you are using a Node version that is 8 and above. As of Docusaurus 1.2.0, Node 6 is not supported anymore and the minimum supported version is Node 8. As stated in the documentation:

> You have to be on Node >= 8.x and Yarn >= 1.5.

You could use a tool like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage your Node versions.